# Vertical list of elements, where each row shrinks its width to match the inner content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a vertical list, where each row shrinks its width to perfectly contain its inner content (versus the default `div` behavior of expanding its width to fill the container).

I'd like to do this with only **one** HTML element for each row (no extra wrapping divs).

The following code does exactly what I want, but it doesn't work in Safari (bug?).

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px
}
.row-item {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* this will shrink the width to the inner content
        in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari */
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row-item'>Item #1</div>
  <div class='row-item'>Another Item...</div>
  <div class='row-item'>Item No. 3</div>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen with the above code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woKYqx

I know that it is trivial to solve this problem by adding a wrapping div and then using `display: inline-block` on the inner element (or several other similar solutions).

However, it seems like it should be possible to solve this without adding extra HTML elements. It is a fairly simple layout.

Is there a cross-browser way to do this with a **single HTML element** for each row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `margin-right: auto` to push the element all the way to the left, which also forces the item to take the width of its content.

This is a good method but, as you've noted, it fails in Safari.

A simple alternative is to use `align-self: flex-start` on the flex items:

```
.row-item {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  align-self: flex-start;  /* NEW */
  /* margin-right: auto;  (can be kept or removed) */
}
```

OR, just use `align-items: flex-start` on the flex container.

```
.container {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start; /* NEW */
  width: 300px
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can erase all flex stuff and use `float:left` and `clear:left` on the children, and `overflow-x: hidden` on the parent:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNjQJJ

Answer (score -1):

When you are using display: flex you should also use the vendor prefixes for it. 
too support older versions of browsers 
when in doubt check up on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com)

```
.container {
 display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
 display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
 display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
 display: flex;
 /* ETC */
}
```

NOTE: caniuse.com have written about bugs being reported about flexbox childrens height in safari.